# python regular expression substitute

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to find the value of "taxid" in a large number of strings similar to one given below. For this particular string, the 'taxid' value is '9606'. I need to discard everything else.   The "taxid" may appear anywhere in the text, but will always be followed by a ":" and then number.

```
score:0.86|taxid:9606(Human)|intact:EBI-999900
```

How to write regular expression for this in python.

Comment: Are there multiple `taxid`s? On another note, your description is not of a substitute, but of a search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'score:0.86|taxid:9606(Human)|intact:EBI-999900'
>>> re.search(r'taxid:(\d+)', s).group(1)
'9606'
```

If there are multiple taxids, use `re.findall`, which returns a list of all matches:

```
>>> re.findall(r'taxid:(\d+)', s)
['9606']
```

Comment: Maybe throw an initial term on there to avoid matching "not_a_taxid:9606"?

Comment: @DSM: Updated as per your suggestion.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, thanks. But Python is driving me crazy. Why I am getting the results as tuple. Sometimes I get the result as string.

Comment: @Curious:  `re.findall` returns a tuple if you have more than one group (parenthesis define a group) in your regular expression.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I'm no good with regex, but isn't there a way to spell "start-of-string or |"?  Otherwise the new one won't catch taxid at the start.

Comment: @DSM.  Yes, but it complicates things.  The pattern would be `r'(^|\|)taxid:(\d+)'`.  Since there are now two groups in the pattern `re.findall` will return tuples instead of strings.  A positive look behind assertion will not work here because look-behind assertions require fixed-width pattern.  Because of this I'm removing the edit from my answer and will allow the comments to do these work of providing further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in lines:
    match = re.match(".*\|taxid:([^|]+)\|.*",line)
    print match.groups()
```